# button to call php to delete mysql row via ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I have a html form button called delete.  Next to the button is an input area.  The logged in user will enter a number corresponding to the ID then press delete.  It should delete the row corresponding to that ID.

For some reason it doesn't work.

This is my html form:

```
  <h3 class="block-head">Delete Job</h3>
<form action="deletejob.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<label>Please Enter Job ID</label><input type="text" name="idnum" id="id"/><br>

     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

This is my php code:

```
mysql_connect("********", "root", "******")
 or die("Connection Failed");
 mysql_select_db("jobslist")or die("Connection Failed");
 $idnum = $_POST['id'];
 $query = "delete from jobs_list where idnum = '".$id."'";
 if(mysql_query($query)){ echo "deleted";}
 else{ echo "fail";}
```

I know about switching to mysqli and that...I just want to see if this method works first.

thanks.

Comment: $idnum = $_POST['idnum']; try it.... PHP will not recognize id - you need form element name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the name of your input is `idnum` yet you are looking in the `$_POST` array for `id` and in your query using the variable `$id` when you declare `$idnum` in the line previous.

```
$idnum = intval($_POST['idnum']);  
$query = "delete from jobs_list where idnum = '".$idnum."'";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to prevent sql injection because the actual id is called id.

Comment: assuming you know not to use mysql_ functions and to look at pdo/mysqli those are the two issues that can be identified from the code you posted. i wrapped the input number in intval to make sure you are actually getting an integer from the input.

Answer (score 3):

PHP receive the data via $_POST as an array of input elements with the key as the NAME of the input field, so you have to change this line:

```
$idnum = $_POST['idnum'];
```

You can also change the input name and don't change the php code:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id"/>
```

It's a typical mistake, don't worry too much about that :P

Answer (score 1):

> You should change the POST value.. and then try

```
$idnum = $_POST['idnum'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the HTML, update the input type id to:

```
id="idnum"
```

then, update the PHP query while fetching the post value to:

```
$idnum = $_POST['idnum'];
```

It should work.